# How to change the Symfony2 Behat Bundle default Feature context file (FeatureContext.php by default)

Tags: php, symfony, behat

I use Symfony2 [BehatBundle](https://github.com/Behat/BehatBundle/tree/v1.0.0), version=v1.0.0 and I want to **change the name of the main feature context file**. Now when I run the behat using command:

```
app/console --env=test behat @NameOfMyBundle
```

file src/NameOfMyBundle/Features/Context/**FeatureContext.php** is used

I want to use custom main feature file, for example src/NameOfMyBundle/Features/Context/**MyCustomContext.php** but I don't know how. According to the [behat documentation](http://docs.behat.org/guides/4.context.html#context-class-requirements):

> By convention, the context class should be called FeatureContext, but this could be easily changed through the cli configuration.

However, this configuration option is nowhere to be found. I tried something like:

```
app/console --env=test behat @NameOfMyBundle --context "MyCustomContext"
```

but it fails.

Does anyone know how to change this main feature context file (preferably, using cli)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The context class can be changed in the configuration file: http://docs.behat.org/guides/7.config.html#context

Environment variables can be used as well: http://docs.behat.org/guides/7.config.html#environment-variable

The bundle is no longer maintained. Use the extension instead: http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/cookbooks/1.symfony2_integration.html#installing-and-enabling-symfony2-extension

Comment: Thanks for this.
However, is there any option to do this using command line? In my current project (legacy code) I don't have behat.yml file. My only configuration is app/config_test.yml file with:

mink:
    base_url: %bdd_browser_url%
    default_session: symfony
    browser_name: chrome
    selenium2:
        wd_host: %selenium_server%

Comment: Read my second sentence again, it suggests how to do this from cli. Furthermore, looks like your app/config_test.yml is your behat.yml file (you can change config file to be used from cli).

Comment: Thanks, it was useful. The problem was solved by using standard FeatureContext and different subcontexts with $this->useContext('someSubcontext', new SomeSubcontext()) inside. Thanks for help.